# Why I cannot get nodes for "var"

Tags: java, xml, xpath

Any reason that I cannot get the "var" nodes? I do not see anything print out. So the problem is that nodes returns nothing. Please help. Thanks a lot!

Here is my java code:

```
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(responseBody)));
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
// XPath Query for showing all nodes value
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/vxml/form/var");

NodeList nodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node = nodes.item(i);
    System.out.println("test");
}
```

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<vxml xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/vxml" xmlns:voxeo="http://community.voxeo.com/xmlns/vxml" version="2.1">
<form id="XCONTENT">
  <catch event="invalidResponse">
     <assign name="responseRetries" expr="responseRetries+1" />
     <clear namelist="CHOICES" />
     <goto nextitem="CHOICES" />
  </catch>
  <var expr="1" name="responseRetries" />
  <var expr="''" name="choice" />
  <var expr="'8750000'" name="ntfnId" />
  <var expr="'8749000,8748000,8747000,8746000'" name="notIds" />
  <var expr="'228971'" name="deviceId" />
  <var expr="'0'" name="nodeId" />
  <var expr="'1'" name="orgId" />
  <var expr="'English'" name="userPreferredLang" />
  <var expr="'slow'" name="ttsRate" />
  <var expr="false" name="isValidationMessage" />
  <var expr="'8750000'" name="processedNotificationIds" />
  <var expr="'1815f630-bda2-45be-b08b-46a51d3aebd4'" name="callSid" />
  <var expr="'BEFORE'" name="authState" />
  <var expr="''" name="authNotificationIds" />
  <var expr="''" name="nodeName" />
  <var expr="false" name="RESPONSE_PLAYED" />
  <var expr="'true'" name="hasContent" />
   </form>
</vxml>
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Copied XML to text file, and copied code, changing it to read XML from file, and it printed `test` 17 times. *(using jdk1.8.0_91)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your elements are in a namespace, but your XPath is looking for elements in no namespace. Search this site for "XPath default namespace" to find thousands of other people who have hit the same problem.